# Dar baixa em [CNPJ] e [CPF]

Tags: debate, tags

Há pouco vi uma pergunta com a *tag* [cnpj](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnpj).

Então, sobre CNPJ. Existe um algoritmo bem simples pra validar... E isso é tudo. Sério.

Qualquer outra dúvida sobre CNPJ:

- Seria na esfera legal, o que é ilegal por aqui, ou...
- ...seria sobre como formatar um campo para ter uma máscara de CNPJ, o que pode ser abordado com outras *tags* como [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) etc.

Vale a pena manter [cnpj](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnpj), ou podemos eliminar essa *tag*?

Tem doze perguntas no momento com essa *tag*. Doze. Dá pra matar em três minutos.

**Edição:** defenestramos a [cnpj](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnpj), a próxima na fila é a [cpf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpf) com doze perguntas no momento.

**Edição de novo:** missão cumprida, valeu pessoal :)

Comment: Não vejo motivos para manter, mesmo que seja para explicar o algorítimo do CNPJ ou CPF, de qualquer forma o uso é tão raro e *inutil* que é melhor remover mesmo, se for validação ou mascara tags não é necessário ser tão especifico. Acho que deve matar sim.

Comment: Por um momento, meu instinto foi entrar nessa pergunta e votar pra migrar :p

Comment: Tem a [cpf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpf) também.

Comment: Acham que valeria a pena usar a tag [tag:brasil] no lugar de cnpj e cpf?

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que não. Não tem a ver com programação, da mesma forma que as tags cpf e cnpj.

Comment: É uma tag meio estranha mesmo a brasil, mas foi criada com intenção nobre: distinguir conteúdo relevante apenas para o brasil de conteúdo relevante para portugal e outros. Só que nunca "pegou".

Comment: Me parece desnecessária.

Comment: Sobrou só uma pergunta, mas só porque a única *tag* dela é CNPJ e eu não sei que *tag* colocar no lugar.

Comment: @Renan agora não tem nenhuma, o que acha de aproveitar o "rebote" pra dar baixa na tag [tag:cpf]? Ou acha que devemos discutir sobre ela?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu acho que a *tag* pra CPF merece o mesmo tratamento que CNPJ.

Comment: @Renan não seria o caso de editar o post e tratar do CPF junto, já que ainda não tem resposta?

Comment: @Bacco boa ideia.

Comment: Queimem o CPF! Queimem o CNPJ! Queimem o CEP! Queimem o Brasil!

Comment: CPF baixado, finalmente

Comment: CPF ressurgiu das cinzas! Ao ataque, legião!!!! **EDIT** a fera foi derrotada novamente. Devemos ficar sempre alerta e nunca baixar a guarda